# Type-safe flattening of nested collections/structures in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-safety, lambdaj

I would like to **flatten arbitrary deeply nested collections/structures** of elements of some type T in Java, optimally with

- only having a live view and not a copied collection;
- not only handling Collections, but also Iterator, arrays of T of arbitrary dimension, Iterable, and all these structures arbitrarily mixed and nested;
- statical type-safety.

Is there a java library which can handle this?

---

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) seems to only handle one nesting level, i.e. `Collection<Collection<T>>` --flatten--> `Collection<T>`.

[lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) looks promising: can I somehow combine `on()`, `asIterator()` and `flattenIterator()` to achieve this? In a statically type-safe manner?

Comment: Not based on either of the above, but perhaps a `DeepIterator` class that is constructed with a `Collection` whose `next()` method looks at the next `Object` and if it is a `instanceof Collection` then pushes the current `iterator` on `Stack` and recurses into that `Collection`'s iterator.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented some iterators that way. Having to make a case distinction for arrays of arbitrary dimensions and Iterators is pretty fiddly, though. And there is no static type-safety :( Since lambdaj probably implements it at least as good, I don't think I should do that implementation...

Comment: What do you mean static type safety here? Since the Collection (ADG actually) can contain elements of different types, the Iterator can only provide `Object`s. Am I missing something?

Comment: At least for all arbitrarily deeply nested Collections you can detect at compile time that the leafs are all of type T. Since lambdaj offers a lot of functions that feel dynamically typed (e.g. invoking a method on each item), but are actually still statically typed, I hope lambdaj can handle even more structures and checks at compile time.

Comment: `DeepIterator` aproach sounds promising, but I don't think you can achieve general and statical type-safety solution. I don't see how you can even express such entity in Java.

Comment: Collection<T extends Interface1>, and each element is either a single element or a lambdaj proxy object implementing Interface1.

Comment: Or make a disjoint union data type with functional java's fj.data.Either. So on the whole, it's definitely not easy, but static typing can often do more then you'd expect at first glance (even without flow dependent types or type inference).

Comment: Regarding `Collection<T extends Interface1?` what would happen if some nested element is not a kind of `Interface1`? Omit those elements? Throw exception?

Comment: As I've said, I am interested in static type-safety, so the compiler would give me an error (lambdaj's proxy object implementing Interface1 is supposed to be statically type-safe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava will probably support this *eventually* :

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=174

(It might be easiest to read that from the bottom up, since the thinking on it has shifted a few times over its lifetime.)

Answer (score 1):

Not based on either of the above, but perhaps a DeepIterator class that is constructed with a Collection whose next() method looks at the next Object and if it is a instanceof Collection then pushes the current iterator on Stack and recurses into that Collection's iterator.

Comment: I'm having a deja-vu reading your post ;) But it's a good idea to give it as a real answer - let's see its votes...

Comment: @DaveBall If I can be downvoted for a correct answer maybe I can upvoted for an partial answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help: `Arrays.deepToString(myCollection.toArray())`

Comment: For retrieving Strings, yes. For retrieving elements of type T, this unfortunately does not help.

Comment: @daveball i think it would still work, you wanna check code for deepToString and also depends on whether type T has implemented toString

Comment: `deepToString()` does not handle Arrays either. That is, if one of the elements is an `Array` the it will call `toString` on it, not `Arrays.deepToString`. Strange but true.

Comment: @DaveBall I think Suraj means `getDeclaredMethods()` which will tell you if the `Class` implements `toString()` itself. But I don't know how that helps. You are not interested in knowing what the string representation of the object is, you want an Iterator over all the objects