# How to flatten all items from a nested Java Collection into a single List?

Tags: java, list, loops, recursion, collections

Given a complex nested collection of objects such as:

```
Set<List<Map<String, List<Object>>>> complexNestedCollection;
```

Does a generic method exist to flatten this out and get a single `List` of all `Object`s contained within?

A few details:

1. The list shouldn't include collection objects themselves or map keys - only the values at the lowest level.
2. It should follow the same ordering where possible - so in the example, items in the list would be in order, whereas ordering of maps/sets would depend on the implementation.
3. It could optionally exclude duplicates
4. **UPDATE:** It should ideally detect/handle circular references at any level, e.g. a `List<List<Object>>` where the outer List contains itself as a member. (Credit to Adrian Jałoszewski for mentioning this in the comments below).

*Note: The actual use case is to get all Strings from a `List<List<String>>`, which can be done easily enough with two loops but it made me wonder about the general case.*

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431006/type-safe-flattening-of-nested-collections-structures-in-java

Comment: this can also done with loops: iterate over the `Set`, the `List`, the `values()` of the `Map` and finally the lists

Comment: @Marco Thanks but I'm looking for a solution for the *general* case.

Comment: Does it allow for cycles? Example `List<List> list` which contains itself.

Comment: @AdrianJałoszewski Good point - guess this would cause a `StackOverflowException` in most of the recursive implementations below. (Would need to investigate whether this occurs in the suggested API methods.) Have now added point (4) to the question.

Comment: Please note that the generic methods proposed can only work for simple use cases, you cannot manage cases where your have for example a `List<List<Object>>` and in one of the lists you have a `List` too as object that you should get as a List once flatterned because you can know at runtime the generic type of your list due to type erasure so you cannot know that we don't necessary want to flattern a given list in a middle of objects

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Having thought about it a bit more I'm currently regarding the cyclic reference issue as an "edge case" - think it's unlikely to often be a problem in practice and suppose a runtime exception here would at least highlight the "unusual" nature of the data.

Comment: I'm not talking about cyclic reference, I'm talking about this for example `List<List<Object>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1), Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1)))` here we would expect to get `1` and `Arrays.asList(1))` in our resulting list while with a generic method you will get `1` and `1` so if you remove duplicates only `1` which is totally wrong

Comment: From requirement (1) I *would* expect to get `1` and `1` here rather then `1` and `Array.asList(1)`.

Comment: If you using a language with functional features, I would suggest using `flatMap`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, you could do that with the [`Stream API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) thanks to the method [`flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) as next:

```
// 1. Convert the Set as a Stream of List<Map<String, List<Object>>>
// 2. Extract the elements of the lists to get a Stream of Map<String, List<Object>>
// 3. Extract values of the maps to get a Stream of List<Object>
// 4. Extract the elements of the lists to get a Stream of Object
// 5. Get rid of duplicates
// 6. Collect the result as a List of Object
List<Object> result = complexNestedCollection.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> `<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends
>   R>> mapper)`
>
> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element
>   of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by
>   applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped
>   stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.
>   (If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)

---

For **previous versions** of `Java`, you can still use [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) from **Google Guava** to replace the `Stream` and use [`transformAndConcat(Function<? super E,? extends Iterable<? extends T>> function)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)) instead of `flatMap` to flatten your collection.

**The previous code snippet would then be rewritten as next:**

```
List<Object> result =
    new ArrayList<>(
        new LinkedHashSet<>(
            FluentIterable.from(complexNestedCollection)
                .transformAndConcat(
                    new Function<List<Map<String, List<Object>>>, Iterable<Map<String, List<Object>>>> () {
                        public Iterable<Map<String, List<Object>>> apply(final List<Map<String, List<Object>>> input) {
                            return input;
                        }
                    }
                ).transformAndConcat(
                    new Function<Map<String, List<Object>>, Iterable<List<Object>>> () {
                        public Iterable<List<Object>> apply(final Map<String, List<Object>> input) {
                            return input.values();
                        }
                    }
                ).transformAndConcat(
                    new Function<List<Object>, Iterable<Object>> () {
                        public Iterable<Object> apply(final List<Object> input) {
                            return input;
                        }
                    }
                ).toList()
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The Java 8 method looks promising but unfortunately the project I'm working on is stuck on Java 7 - so I used an online tool to try it out (using data provided in another answer) - see http://rextester.com/NLQ86944 This is currently giving an error - perhaps you might be able to advise or help to get it working? (Thanks for providing a Java 7 alternative but am less keen on this one as from your example it looks like it wouldn't be translatable into a single "one size fits all" generic method?)

Comment: check my comment on your question, generic methods are not the right approach unless you want to take the risk to get incorrect results due to a potential collection in a middle of objects in a list

Comment: my solution is not meant to be generic, it relies on the type of the collections to be sure at runtime that you get what you want

Comment: In that case, one of the custom solutions may be preferable to answer this particular question - it has always asked for a generic solution. (That's not to say this answer isn't of interest though - it definitely is.)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if this exact implementation would work, as it's full of unchecked warnings and other dangerous stuff, but you should get the general idea.

```
public static Set<Object> recursiveExtract(Object stuff) {

    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();

    if(stuff instanceof Iterable) {
        for(Object o : (Iterable<?>)stuff) {
            set.addAll(recursiveExtract(o));
        }
    } else if(stuff instanceof Map) {
        for(Object o : ((Map<?, ? extends Object>) stuff).values()) {
            set.addAll(recursiveExtract(o));
        }
    } else {
        set.add(stuff);
    }

    return set;
}
```

You can also use `List<Object>` if you insist on List, but then you could get duplicate results, or `LinkedHashSet<Object>` if you care about the order.

---

Please instead of downvotes, give me suggestions for improvement. It's nicer.

Comment: I was working on something similar. I tried to make use of the generic type but couldn't figure it out. I guess using ´Object´ is the only choice. You'll have to do type checks anyway.

Comment: @MightyPork Good start, thanks - certainly won't be downvoting! But makes me wonder - surely someone somewhere must have done this before...

Comment: You are discarding the original order. You may use LinkedHashSet instead.

Comment: Yes, if the order is important. But then, List would work just as well.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a FlattenEverythingButTheKitchenSink class, a slightly modified version of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186270/java-flatten-an-array-using-recursion/40186952#40186952). It was tested with Java 7 and Java 8.

It works with Lists, Sets, Maps, Queues, and even Arrays of arbitrary depth.
It compiles and runs without warning, and I couldn't find any counterexample. Hence the class name :)

If you want a List of objects with possible duplicates, use flatten, if you want a Set, use uniqFlatten.

EDITED: Refactoring to avoid code repetition.

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;


// Answer for
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144826/how-to-flatten-all-items-from-a-nested-collection-into-a-single-list
public class FlattenEverythingButTheKitchenSink
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][][] int3dArray = { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } },
                { { 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15 }, { 16, 17, 18 } },
                { { 19, 20, 21 }, { 22, 23, 24 }, { 25, 26, 27 }, { 28 }, { 29, 30 } } };
        String[][] string2dArray = { { "He, llo" }, { "Wo", "rld" } };
        String[] stringArray = { "Hello", "World" };
        Set<Integer> integersSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        integersSet.add(1);
        integersSet.add(2);
        integersSet.add(3);

        Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
        stringMap.put("key1", "value1");
        stringMap.put("key2", "value2");
        stringMap.put("key3", "value3");

        Queue<String> qe = new LinkedList<String>();
        qe.add("x");
        qe.add("y");
        qe.add("z");

        Object[] objectArray = { "Hell", 0, "W", 0, "orld", integersSet, stringMap, qe };

        List<Object> mixList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        mixList.add("String");
        mixList.add(3);
        mixList.add(string2dArray);

        System.out.println(flatten(int3dArray));
        System.out.println(flatten(flatten(int3dArray)));
        System.out.println(flatten(3));
        System.out.println(flatten(stringArray));
        System.out.println(flatten(string2dArray));
        System.out.println(flatten(objectArray));
        System.out.println(flatten(mixList));

        mixList.add(int3dArray);

        System.out.println(uniqFlatten(mixList));
    }

    public static List<Object> flatten(Object object) {
        return (List<Object>) recursiveFlatten(object, true);
    }

    public static Set<Object> uniqFlatten(Object object) {
        return (Set<Object>) recursiveFlatten(object, false);
    }

    private static Collection<Object> recursiveFlatten(Object object, Boolean allowDuplicates) {
        Collection<Object> setOrList;
        if (allowDuplicates) {
            setOrList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        } else {
            setOrList = new LinkedHashSet<Object>();
        }
        if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(object); i++) {
                setOrList.addAll(recursiveFlatten(Array.get(object, i), allowDuplicates));
            }
        } else if (object instanceof Map) {
            for (Object element : ((Map<?, ?>) object).values()) {
                setOrList.addAll(recursiveFlatten(element, allowDuplicates));
            }
        } else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
            for (Object element : (Iterable<?>) object) {
                setOrList.addAll(recursiveFlatten(element, allowDuplicates));
            }
        } else {
            setOrList.add(object);
        }
        return setOrList;
    }
}
```

It outputs :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3]
[Hello, World]
[He, llo, Wo, rld]
[Hell, 0, W, 0, orld, 1, 2, 3, value1, value2, value3, x, y, z]
[String, 3, He, llo, Wo, rld]
[String, 3, He, llo, Wo, rld, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

and shouldn't have any problem with a

```
Set<List<Map<String, List<Object>>>> complexNestedCollection;
```

It would also work with a

```
Set<List<Map<String, List<int[][][][]>>>>
```

The initialisation code wouldn't be pretty though :D

Comment: From a brief code review this looks great. The only initial comment I'd have is there is duplication between `flatten` and `uniqFlatten` - think there must be a fairly simple refactor here into a single method that takes a "unique" boolean parameter and then appropriately assigns a Collection<Object> with either the `ArrayList` or `LinkedHashSet`. Also out of interest, which parts of this require Java 8?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My first implementation used Lambdas, that's where the comment came from. I just tested this code with Java 7 and it worked fine. I'll try to refactor the code to avoid duplicate methods. uniqFlatten was an afterthought.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [LambdaJ](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)'s flatten function.

```
List<Object> simpleCollection = flatten(flatten(flatten(complexNestedCollection)));
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion to solve the problem is to create a class which flattens the collections and maps recursively which memorizes the collections and maps already visited to handle circular dependencies. It's a straight forawart implementation of the DFS algorithm.

```
public class CollectionFlattener {
    private List<Object> returnList = new LinkedList<>();
    private Visited visited = new Visited();

    public CollectionFlattener(Object o) {
        handle(o);
    }

    private void handle(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Map) {
            handleMap((Map) o);
        } else if (o instanceof Collection) {
            handleCollection((Collection) o);
        } else {
            returnList.add(o);
        }
    }

    private void handleCollection(Collection<?> collection) {
        if (!visited.isVisited(collection)) {
            visited.visit(collection);
            collection.forEach(this::handle);
        }
    }

    private void handleMap(Map<?, ?> map) {
        if (!visited.isVisited(map)) {
            visited.visit(map);
            handleCollection(map.values());
        }
    }

    public Collection<Object> getFlatCollection() {
        return new LinkedList<>(returnList);
    }
}
```

The `Visited` class has to offer a way to check whether the object we encountered is THE SAME (this is the reason I'm using the `==` operator here instead of `equals`). This is the only way we can reduce circular dependencies without loosing information about collections which by coincidence contain the same elements.

```
public class Visited {
    private List<Object> visited = new LinkedList<>();

    public void visit(Object o) {
        if (!isVisited(o)) {
            visited.add(o);
        }
    }
    public boolean isVisited(Object o) {
        long count = visited.stream().filter(object -> object == o).count();
        return count != 0;
    }
}
```

The only thing which is needed here is a `null` check, but it's not necessary to understand the logic behind this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering what the scenario could be and if it weren't better to define some specific data structure, such as a tree. But anyway:

I would avoid generics as java's typesystem is too simplistic to handle recursive types:

```
public static Collection flatten(Iterable collection, boolean duplicatesAllowed) {
    // create the result collection it just once and 
    ///pass it around as an accumulator
    // it gives you better time/space complexity
    Collection result = duplicatesAllowed ? new ArrayList() : new LinkedHashSet();
    flattenImpl(collection, result);
    return result;
}
```

This is supported by two private functions that do the actual extraction filling up the provided `result` collection:

```
private static void flattenImpl(Object obj, Collection result) {
    if (obj instanceof Iterable) {
        flattenImpl((Iterable)obj, result);
    } 
    else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        flattenImpl( ((Map)obj).values(), result);
    } 
    else {
        result.add(obj);
    }
}

private static void flattenImpl(Iterable collection, Collection result) {
    for(Object o : collection) {
        flattenImpl(o, result);
    }
}
```