# Nested List In One List

Tags: java, list

How to convert a nested list into a single list in java?

```
List list = new ArrayList();
List newList = new ArrayList();
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list1.add(2);

list1.add(4);

list.add(5);
list.addAll(list1);
list.add(6);
```

How can i add the elements of list to newList so that when i print newList

it prints

```
[5,2,4,6]
```

Comment: whats the use case here?

Comment: Don't use raw-types!

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to [add all](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(int,%20java.util.Collection)) of the elements into a specific point in the list?

Comment: By the way, there is no nested list in the code you've included.  A nested list would be a list of lists eg `List<List<Integer>> nestedList;`

Comment: I rolled back your edit.... you can't go and change the core concepts of your question after there are 3 answers to your original question.

Comment: yeah i know but if you see the code you can think what i asked ?okay

Comment: If you the guys help me i would be very thank full

Comment: as I said before, that you should ask a different question, if you have a different question. (but first search for duplicates), like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20144826/1305253) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7431006/1305253)

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is something you're not telling us, it is simply a repeat of what you have already done:

```
newList.addAll(list);
```

As has been said in the comments though, you really should be using full generic typing for your list variables:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: it will not work as when you iterate over the list list the frist element is 5 which is  integer and the second element of this list i mean list is a list [2,4] this is the problem

Comment: @user3098769 - it will work.... because the second element is not a list, because you added the content with `addAll` and not `add`

Comment: suppose if i used add instead of addAll to add the list1 to list then can you give me a solution

Comment: If you use add, instead of addAll, it would be a different question then, wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah can you give me a solution if i used add instead of addAll

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), and you can call `newList.addAll(list);` -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- diamond operator, Java 7 and up.
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.addAll(list1);
    list.add(6);
    newList.addAll(list); // <-- here
    System.out.println(newList);
}
```

Output is the requested

```
[5, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already used a possible way with

`list.addAll(list1)`

Another way would be walking through the list resp. using it's iterator
to fetch and put all items into the newList.

Have a look at the API for more detailed info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
      if(list.get(i) instanceof Integer){ 
           newlist.add(list.get(i));
      }else{
           newlist.addAll((ArrayList)list.get(i));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The list that has to hold another list should be defined properly, rest working will be same. Refer below:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class demo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        nestedList.add(list);
        System.out.println(nestedList);
    }
}
```